# bash script, check port response with bash's built-in /dev/tcp, time delay | hangs | speed up

Tags: bash, tcp, port, timeout, delay

With this scripts i check if a host is response on a given port with the **bash's built-in /dev/tcp**.

I can use ip address or domains(hostnames).

**Script 1**

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST_NAME="127.1"
HOST_PORT="80"

if ( (exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${HOST_NAME}/${HOST_PORT}) 2> /dev/null); then
    echo -e "PORT: ${HOST_PORT} | ON"
    else
    echo -e "PORT: ${HOST_PORT} | OFF"
fi

exit;
```

**Script 2**

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST_NAME="127.1"

for HOST_PORT in {1..1000}
do

if ( (exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${HOST_NAME}/${HOST_PORT}) 2> /dev/null); then
    echo -e "PORT: ${HOST_PORT} | ON"
    else
    echo -e "PORT: ${HOST_PORT} | OFF"
fi
done

exit;
```

Script 3

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST_NAME="127.1"
declare -A PORT_ON

for HOST_PORT in {1..65535}
do
    if ( (exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${HOST_NAME}/${HOST_PORT}) 2> /dev/null); then
        PORT_ON[${HOST_PORT}]="ON"
    fi
done

for i in ${!PORT_ON[*]}
do
    echo -e "$i : ${PORT_ON[$i]}"
done

exit;
```

On some of our local and online domains **Script 3** hangs on some ports and takes longer to jump to the next port scan, for example on ssh(because of firewalls or other services). How can i manage this that it continues straight away and is it possible to speed the script up, it takes a long time, when i scan all 65535 ports an.

**My GNU/Linux Distro:**

```
Distributor ID: Debian

Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Release:        10

Codename:       buster

4.19.0-16-amd64
```

**My /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

I can only install  from this repos.

*bash script, check port response with bash's built-in /dev/tcp, time delay | hangs | speed up*

**how can i speed up and terminate the time delay?**

Answer (score 4):

Run this with `timeout`.

I put a timer varible to check the running time.

It seems you can't speed up the scritp more than `0.01`.

If this scirpt is executed with `0.001`, you will only see the reslut of the timer varible but no other reslut.

Even with `1`, `0.1` or `0.01`, you will always get the same reslut.

I tested this scirpt with Ubuntu 22.04 and set the ports to 10000.

```
#!/bin/bash

starttime=$(date +%s)
HOST_NAME="127.0.0.1"
declare -A PORT_ON

for HOST_PORT in {1..10000}
do
 if((timeout 0.1 bash -c "</dev/tcp/${HOST_NAME}/${HOST_PORT}") 2> /dev/null); then
    PORT_ON[${HOST_PORT}]="ON";
  fi
done

for i in ${!PORT_ON[*]}
do
  echo -e "$i: ${PORT_ON[$i]}"
done

endtime=$(date +%s)

echo "runtime: $(($endtime - $starttime))"
```